# How match email address with regex expression?

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-like

the match to find email has wrong regex expression, leading to missing  emails that should have been otherwise populated in the output.

Below is the query

```
case when regexp_like(email,'^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$')
```

The above regex expression doesn't match emails like
BILL@AMERITRUST-MORTGAGE.COM
Instead it returns null when such emails are encountered.

Comment: looks valid regex according to https://regex101.com/ which language you are trying it on?

Comment: please check an answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/719543/7131875

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this statement and it worked:

```
select 1
  from dual
 where regexp_like('BILL@AMERITRUST-MORTGAGE.COM', '^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$');
```

The minus character must be the last one in the [...].